# ¿Cómo se puede reemplazar los 0.0000 por NaN en un Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola estoy trabajando con Dataframes, y quisiera saber como puedo cambiar los elementos '0.0000' por 'NaN' en las columnas 'D1' y 'D2', mi código es:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_csv('MI_ARCHIVO.txt', header = 0, delim_whitespace = True)

data['D1'].replace(["0.0000"], "NaN"))

print(data['D1'])
```

El archivo txt es:

```
Dias        D1            D2            D3
  1      1000.0567     900.5986     1070.8760
  2       975.5000     800.7000      800.8700
  3         0.0000     780.0000      750.8090
  4       700.0908       0.0000     1080.0000
  5      2000.1000     950.0000     1080.8000
  6         0.0000     879.7968     1100.2000
  7         0.0000       0.0000      609.3000
  8      9000.1000     700.0000     1000.0000
  9         0.0000       0.0000     2000.9000
 10         0.0000       0.0000     1500.2000
 11         0.0000       0.0000     1700.2560
 12         0.0000       0.0000      150.0000
 13         0.0000       0.0000     1250.2000
 14       700.6070       0.0000      800.0000
 15      1200.0000       0.0000      300.0000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto:

```
data['D1'].replace(["0.0000"], "NaN"))
```

Tiene dos problemas:

1. Lo que estás intentando es tratar a tus columnas como cadenas, el tema es que no lo son, son del tipo `float`  `"NaN"` no es la constante `NaN`. Deberías usar `np.nan` en todo caso
2. El [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) reemplaza, pero no sobre el mismo objeto, sino que retorna una copia, por lo que deberías asignar el valor a la misma columna.

Finalmente te quedaría algo así:

```
import numpy as np

data['D1'] = data['D1'].replace([0], [np.nan])
```

También puedes resolverlo de una forma más clásica:

```
data.loc[data['D1'] == 0, 'D1'] = np.nan
```